# How Blender exports material node animations

Tags: animation-nodes, shader-nodes

I tried to create a UV animation and a texture animation, and I want to import these animations into a GLB file for front-end display. However, it seems that neither of these animations can be exported. Do you have any way to export the animations made on material nodes to a GLB file

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures